# inputdata on CPU is more than global memory on GPU

Tags: opencl

if input data on CPU  is more than global memory of GPU then how it can be handeled?
in OpenCL if inputdata size is more than Global memory on the GPU than what code we can write or where to write the code in opencl?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You compute it by smaller patches. On the CPU, you make divisions and send divisions(patch) to GPU, then get the results and concatenate them to get all answer.

Comment: Specification is equal to your questions :)

Comment: 100 by 100 for 10000 times

Comment: yes, very inefficient but doable.